# Importing wooden trinkets into New Zealand and Australia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, new-zealand

I have been travelling and have picked up some neat wooden trinkets.

I will be holidaying in New Zealand before travelling back to Australia.

I know that both countries have restrictions on such products.

Obviously I should declare such items, but I want to avoid losing the items at the border.

What are customs specifically looking for, and how can I avoid them confiscating them?

Comment: [This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/80922/54781) to a similar question should get you started.

Comment: Are you importing with the intention of reselling them, or are they merely souvenirs?

Answer (score 4):

Customs would look for a certificate that you have had them professionally fumigated to avoid bringing in bugs that does not exist natively in those countries

You can also check because last time I went to NZ they offered this fumigation service at the airport on arrival for a few but please check first before you go to avoid loosing items due to misunderstandings

Comment: in places that attract NZ and Aus tourists, there are often little stickers on the souvenirs saying "treated wood". I had no problem with the little bowls I bought in Fiji.

Comment: Professional fumigation is only necessary for untreated wood.  Most treated wood articles are fine to bring in, no certificate needed, but it's always wise to declare.